How to get the request body from a request using Web API project with .NET 8?
I'm trying to read the body of a request but I always get an empty string, I'm using ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API and I do this based on the following code:
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class StatusWAController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<StatusWAController> _logger;
    private readonly IstatusMensajeWAService _statusMensajeWAService;

    public StatusWAController(ILogger<StatusWAController> logger, IstatusMensajeWAService statusMensajeWAService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _statusMensajeWAService = statusMensajeWAService;
    }

    [HttpPost(Name = "CreateResponseWA")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateResponseWA(CreateResponseWADto createResponseWADto)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("Request started: ");

        Request.EnableBuffering();
        Request.Body.Position = 0;

        var body = await new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync(); //Always empty
        _logger.LogWarning("Request finished: " + body);//Only shows --> "Request finished: "

        return Ok(body)
    }
}

I will appreciate the correct way to read the request body.

Have you tried the [FromBody] attribute on a method parameter?


I'm trying to read the body of a request but I always get an empty
string, I'm using Asp.Net Web Api with .Net 8.0

Based on your scenario and description this can be achieve either using middleware or you can directly read request body within the controller.
As request.Body is the type of stream class thus, we can use StreamReder to extract the request body which could return us the expected results.
However, if you want to read it from controller you would face one challenge, Request.Body does not support rebinding, so it can only be read once. But when you read from your controller parameter it first bind the model, so you would get the request body empty.
In this scenario you only can read the request body directly from request from body as string Request.Body.ReadAsStringAsync() and you have to remove the model from controller action.
Thus, if you want to read the request body with model binding use Middleware approach but if you want to read inside controller, then you have to remove the model and need to read request body using request body string which I have shown here as well.
Let's examine that in practice:
Custom Request Reader Model:
public class CreateResponseWADto
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

Note: For demonstrating the sample I am using above class to bind my request body.
Request Body Reader Middleware:
public class ReadRequestBodyMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public ReadRequestBodyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var requestContent = new StringBuilder();

        requestContent.AppendLine("=== Request Info ===");
        requestContent.AppendLine($"method = {context.Request.Method.ToUpper()}");
        requestContent.AppendLine($"path = {context.Request.Path}");

        requestContent.AppendLine("-- headers");
        foreach (var (headerKey, headerValue) in context.Request.Headers)
        {
            requestContent.AppendLine($"header = {headerKey}    value = {headerValue}");
        }

        requestContent.AppendLine("-- body");
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();
        var requestReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);
        var content = await requestReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        requestContent.AppendLine($"body = {content}");

        Console.WriteLine(requestContent.ToString());
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        await _next(context);

    }
}

Note: You can keep the existing request body, for the test I am rebinding with the modified value in request.Body = stream; but you can customize as per your needs.
Calling Middleware In Program.cs:
app.UseMiddleware<ReadRequestBodyMiddleware>();

Output:

Using Controller:
If you want to read the request body within the controller, in that scenario, you could do as following:
public static class RequestExtensions
{
    public static async Task<string> ReadAsStringAsync(this Stream requestBody, bool leaveOpen = false)
    {
        using StreamReader reader = new(requestBody, leaveOpen: leaveOpen);
        var readReqeustBodyAsString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return readReqeustBodyAsString;
    }
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateResponseWA()
{
    var requestBody = await Request.Body.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(requestBody.ToString());

    return Ok(requestBody.ToString());
}

Output:

Note: Please refer to this official document for additional details.

Your request body has already been populated into createResponseWADto object. That is why Request.Body is always empty, .NET Core already read it. So your code will be something like:
_logger.LogWarning("Request finished: " + createResponseWADto.ToString()); // if ToString() will serialize this object 

return Ok(createResponseWADto);


I'm embarrassed to say it took me a couple of minutes to realize it, but I was making GET requests so of course there was no HttpRequest body. Once I switched to a POST request I was able to convert the body content to a string in my middleware but after I did it was wiped clean and the application code wasn't able to process the request. Calls to request.Body.Position and request.Body.Seek() both generated exceptions.
I remedied the issue by copying the Request.Body to a MemoryStream, reading that to a string, then setting the Request.Body to my MemoryStream.
 public static async Task<string> ReadRequestBody(HttpRequest request)
 {

     var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
     await request.Body.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
     using StreamReader reader = new(memoryStream, leaveOpen: true);

     memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     var bodyContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

     memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     request.Body = memoryStream;
     return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bodyContent)
         ? null
         : bodyContent;

 }

